# The verb in a condition to the question

Tags: grammar

> If a couple **go** to a restaurant together, do you think they should each pay half the bill?

What do we say go here instead of goes? It is a couple, why wouldn't it "goes"? Could anybody link the rules how we form such questions?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44459/which-is-correct-the-rest-of-the-staff-is-or-are-the-rest-of-my-family-is-or-a/ but read more than the first answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My family \*is\* or My family \*are\*?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74680/my-family-is-or-my-family-are)